# iOS wkWebView, how to check when page jump

Tags: ios, delegates, wkwebview

I want to show the HTML title in navigation bar of the webpage and change the title whenever the page changes. I have tried to use the `didCommitNavigation` delegate method, but when a page request loads, the `didCommitNavigation` method may trigger multiple times. Is there another way I could check if a page changes?

Comment: Have you found the answer you needed ?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way is to check WKNavigationDelegate callback:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.webView.navigationDelegate = self. 

}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {

    NSString *requestURL = navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString;

    NSLog(@"%@", requestURL);

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);

}
```

Don't forget to conform your view controller to  protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mrgrieves for having pointed this.

To know is the view is currently loading content, you can use WKWebView property `loading`

> Set to true if the receiver is still loading content; otherwise,
>   false. The WKWebView class is key-value observing (KVO) compliant for
>   this property.

**Objc-C**

`@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isLoading) BOOL loading;`

**Swift**

`var isLoading: Bool { get }`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414964-loading

---

*Original answer*

You should use [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKNavigationDelegate/webView:didFinishNavigation:)'s method `webView:didFinishNavigation:`

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
{
    NSLog(@"page has changed");
}
```

Comment: Note that this does not tell you when all of the page's resources are fully loaded.  You'll have to use KVO to watch the `isLoading` property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414964-loading?language=objc

Comment: Indeed @mrgrieves ! this is much better to know if the content is still loading 